# Solving linear system of two equations and two unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing some revision and I'm trying to solve simultaneous equations today. 
I need to solve these two pairs of equations and find $x$ and $y$. What would I do?

Do I take off the terms off like e.g. $x$ from both equations and then $y$ and tehn $5$ - $1$? 
I'm not sure.

$$\begin{cases}x + y = 5 \\x - y = 1\end{cases}$$

Thanks everyone for helping out.

Comment: Have you tried adding and subtracting the two equations?

Comment: Hint: Add them together and what do you get? Then, solve for the other vairable.

Comment: Because it's important to understand _why_ to do something, and not just how, here's the justification for "adding the equations together". If you add the same thing to both sides of an equation, it is still true. Since the second equation says that $x-y$ and $1$ are the same thing, we can add one to each side of $x + y = 5$, and the solution set of $x$ and $y$ will not change.

Comment: @HenrySwanson The most important observation on this whole question.

Comment: Oh thanks everyone, I've got it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Elimination by Addition:**

$$ x + y = 5 \\ x - y = 1$$

---

Due to the simplicity of this system, we don't have to do anything to eliminate a variable as we are already given a positive $y$ and a negative $y$.

Add the equation, $x+x=2x$, $y$'s cancel and $5+1=6$:

$$ x + y = 5 \\ x - y = 1\\2x=6$$

$$\\\boxed{x=3}$$
Solve for $y$ by substituting $x$ back into one of the original equations:

$$x+y=5\\3+y=5\\y=5-3$$

$$\boxed{y=2}$$

---

**Using Substitution:**

$$ x + y = 5 \\ x - y = 1$$

Solve for $y$ in one of the equations:

$$x+y=5\\y=-x+5$$

Substitute $y=-x+5$ back into $x-y=1$ :

$$x-(-x+5)=1\\x+x-5=1\\2x=6$$

$$\boxed{x=3}$$

Substitute $x$ back into either of the original equations to find $y$:

$$x+y=5\\3+y=5\\y=5-3$$

$$\boxed{y=2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's why we can "add the equations":

Suppose we know that $$\begin{cases} a = b \\ c = d \end{cases}$$
Then, we have that $$\implies a + c = b + d$$
If you add the ***same*** quantity to both sides of an equation, the resulting equation is *still* true. Since we know $c = d$, we can add one to each side of the equation $a = b$, giving, say, $a + c = b + d$.

In your equations, since the second equation says that $x−y$ and $1$ are the same quantity, we can add one to each side of the equation $x+y=5,$ and the solution(s) for $x$ and $y$ will ***not change***.

Here's why we may **want** to add the equations you're given: we can ***eliminate*** a variable, and then solve for a single unknown, first:
$\begin{align}
x + y & = 5 \\ 
+\; x - y & = 1 \\
\hline \\ 
2x + 0 & = 6
\end{align}$

Solve for $x$, using the fact that $2x = 6$, and then go back to *either* equation to solve for $y$, using your solution to $x$.

E.g. using the first equation: $x + y = 5 \iff y = 5 - x.\;$ Once your know $x$, you can easily now solve for $y$.

Comment: I need to start using those horizontal lines - they are so helpful to the write-up. +1

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{cases}x + y = 5 \\x - y = 1\end{cases}$
This is a very simple system of equation.In answer of amWhy used method is called elimination method(due to elimination of variable).and I want to show you different method which is also useful known as substitution method.

STEP $1$. choose any equation and make some modification so that any of the two variable is on either side of = sign.Suppose I choose eqn 1.
$$x + y = 5$$Now I'm trying to alone $x$ on one side:
$$x=5-y$$

STEP 2: now put this value of $x$ in other eqn (eqn 2)

$$x-y=1$$
putting the value of $x$
$$(5-y)-y=1$$
$$5-y-y=1$$
Now in this eqn we have only one variable so we can easily find out its value like one of your previous question I've answered.
$$5-2y=1$$
$$-2y=1-5$$
$$-2y=-4$$
$$y=\dfrac{-4}{-2}$$
$$y=2$$

STEP 3. Now we have value of one variable $y$.Put this value in any eqn.I'm taking eqn(1)

$$x+y=5$$
$$x+2=5$$
$$x=5-2$$
$$x=3$$

so answer is $x=3\;,y=2$

It will also helpful:
suppose system of eqn is:$\begin{cases}a_1x + b_1y = c_1\\a_2x + b_2y = c_2 \end{cases}$

then:

$$\dfrac{x}{b_1c_2-b_2c_1}=\dfrac{y}{a_2c_1-a_1c_2}=\dfrac{-1}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}$$

Now just put the values of $a_1,b_1,c_1,a_2,b_2,c_2$ and solve like this:

$$\dfrac{x}{b_1c_2-b_2c_1}=\dfrac{-1}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}\;\;,\dfrac{y}{a_2c_1-a_1c_2}=\dfrac{-1}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}$$

In ques.  $a_1=1,b_1=1,c_1=5,a_2=1,b_2=-1,c_2=1$
$$\dfrac{x}{b_1c_2-b_2c_1}=\dfrac{-1}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}\;\;$$
$$\dfrac{x}{6}=\dfrac{-1}{-2}\;\;$$
$$x=\dfrac{6}{2}\;\;$$
$$x=3\;\;$$
same process for $y$